# Is Interlaced Scanning compatibile with Dolby Vision

Tags: video

I've tried setting the resolution to 1080i while Dolby Vision is active and it would revert to 2160p.

So is Interlaced Scanning compatible with Dolby Vision?

I didn't manage to find a definitive answer on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interlaced scanning is a legacy carried from SDR TV to Full-HD era, and it's long deprecated in the UHD time. So yes, Interlaced scanning will be incompatible with any UHD technology, including Dolby Vision (which is an HDR format)